# How to merge accordion and div slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery, accordion

I'm trying to construct a accordion slider plus a `div` slider but having many issues. For example I need a regular slide show with arrows to slide multiple columns to the left and right plus the ability to expand one of the columns via mouse click. Here are a visual examples from my design:

[example #1](http://joncookdesign.com/cd1.jpg)

[example #2](http://joncookdesign.com/cd2.jpg)

I was trying to modify the Kwicks horizontal accordion slider script.

Any help on constructing this would be awesome or if you know of a premade script that does what i'm looking for please send it my way.

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: Images aren't useful demos. Please post some code or link to a proper demo.

Comment: This is what I am currently working with, but having trouble modifying it so as you expand it does not scale down the other columns and also having the ability to slide left/right with arrows.

http://codecanyon.net/item/unleash-jquery-accordion-slider/full_screen_preview/1851823

Comment: here is my current test page: http://joncookdesign.com/CD/gown_test/gowns.html

Comment: So you want nav arrows somewhere on the page? Where? I'm not sure how you'll prevent column squish without horizontal scrolling, which is a UI fail, in my opinion. Maybe I'm not understanding the idea.

Comment: Sadly I did not design this but yes there would be slider nav arrows to show additional accordion columns(or divs). The generic idea is to merge a slideshow slider with a accordion slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/7V9v3/3/ here is what I am currently constructing(not working perfectly)